# Diffie-Hellman in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, integer

Diffie-Hellman is a key exchange that allows 2 people to share a symmetric key without interaction beforehand. First, a person shares an equation; in this case, we use:

$$3^x \mod{17}$$

Next, each person generates a random, usually prime, number. Then, they plug it in the equation. Let's use 5 and 7:

- Alice: \$3^5 \mod{17} \equiv 9 \$
- Bob: \$3^7 \mod{17} \equiv 6 \$

Finally, they share their generated numbers and calculate a "Shared Secret", this is done by (\$U\$ represents your private number):

\$\text{Public}^U \mod{17}\$

In this case:

- Alice: \$6^5 \mod{17} \equiv 2\$
- Bob: \$9^7 \mod{17} \equiv 2\$

Resulting in both parties having the same number. Confused? [See this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBfamv-_do)

I've implemented a function to generate that key. Thoughts?

```
function KeyGen(p1, p2, n){
  // Get a binary string, reverse it
  var bin = String((n).toString(2)).split("").reverse().join("");
  // Base for growth
  var grow = n;
  // Holds values for totals
  var tota = [];
  var total = 1;
  // The main loop
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length; i++){
    tota[i] = 1;
    if(bin.substring(i, i + 1) === "1"){
      for (var l = grow; l > 0;l--){
        tota[i] *= p1;
        tota[i] %= p2;
      }
    }
    total *= tota[i];
    total %= p2;
    grow *= n;
  }
  return total;
}

// Example of gen
var gen = KeyGen(3, 17, 5);
```

Comment: Its very laggy, and I have a feeling the code can be optimized.

Comment: This post is currently being discussed [on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/disagree-on-closure-of-diffee-hellmen-in-javscript).

Comment: I think you will have much better performance if you keep `n` an integer and forget all about the string and array.  Replace `string.substring(i, i+1)` and `array[i]` with `(number >> i) & 1`.  Put `n = n | 0;` near the top, too.

Comment: how to replace Password with Diffie-Hellman private key exchange in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Variable Naming

It took me a while to figure out what are `p1`, `p2` and `n` (and you don't mention them in your example).

## String operation

You could use math operation to do the computation:

```
function KeyGen(base, modulo, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  while(exponent > 0){
    if(exponent % 2 == 1){
        result = (result * base) % modulo;
    }
    base = (base * base) % modulo;
    exponent = exponent >>> 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The memory footprint is then very small (no array required).

## Big numbers

Issues appear when you try to use big integers ([more than 54 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4557509/3207406) - like in your [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113860/diffie-hellman-in-javascript/114135#comment210942_113875)).
To handle them correctly, I would recommand an external library like [BigInt](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js):

```js
var bigInt=function(e){"use strict";function o(e,t){this.value=e,this.sign=t,this.isSmall=!1}function u(e){this.value=e,this.sign=e<0,this.isSmall=!0}function a(e){return-r<e&&e<r}function f(e){return e<1e7?[e]:e<1e14?[e%1e7,Math.floor(e/1e7)]:[e%1e7,Math.floor(e/1e7)%1e7,Math.floor(e/1e14)]}function l(e){c(e);var n=e.length;if(n<4&&O(e,i)<0)switch(n){case 0:return 0;case 1:return e[0];case 2:return e[0]+e[1]*t;default:return e[0]+(e[1]+e[2]*t)*t}return e}function c(e){var t=e.length;while(e[--t]===0);e.length=t+1}function h(e){var t=new Array(e),n=-1;while(++n<e)t[n]=0;return t}function p(e){return e>0?Math.floor(e):Math.ceil(e)}function d(e,n){var r=e.length,i=n.length,s=new Array(r),o=0,u=t,a,f;for(f=0;f<i;f++)a=e[f]+n[f]+o,o=a>=u?1:0,s[f]=a-o*u;while(f<r)a=e[f]+o,o=a===u?1:0,s[f++]=a-o*u;return o>0&&s.push(o),s}function v(e,t){return e.length>=t.length?d(e,t):d(t,e)}function m(e,n){var r=e.length,i=new Array(r),s=t,o,u;for(u=0;u<r;u++)o=e[u]-s+n,n=Math.floor(o/s),i[u]=o-n*s,n+=1;while(n>0)i[u++]=n%s,n=Math.floor(n/s);return i}function g(e,n){var r=e.length,i=n.length,s=new Array(r),o=0,u=t,a,f;for(a=0;a<i;a++)f=e[a]-o-n[a],f<0?(f+=u,o=1):o=0,s[a]=f;for(a=i;a<r;a++){f=e[a]-o;if(!(f<0)){s[a++]=f;break}f+=u,s[a]=f}for(;a<r;a++)s[a]=e[a];return c(s),s}function y(e,t,n){var r,i;return O(e,t)>=0?r=g(e,t):(r=g(t,e),n=!n),r=l(r),typeof r=="number"?(n&&(r=-r),new u(r)):new o(r,n)}function b(e,n,r){var i=e.length,s=new Array(i),a=-n,f=t,c,h;for(c=0;c<i;c++)h=e[c]+a,a=Math.floor(h/f),h%=f,s[c]=h<0?h+f:h;return s=l(s),typeof s=="number"?(r&&(s=-s),new u(s)):new o(s,r)}function w(e,n){var r=e.length,i=n.length,s=r+i,o=h(s),u=t,a,f,l,p,d;for(l=0;l<r;++l){p=e[l];for(var v=0;v<i;++v)d=n[v],a=p*d+o[l+v],f=Math.floor(a/u),o[l+v]=a-f*u,o[l+v+1]+=f}return c(o),o}function E(e,n){var r=e.length,i=new Array(r),s=t,o=0,u,a;for(a=0;a<r;a++)u=e[a]*n+o,o=Math.floor(u/s),i[a]=u-o*s;while(o>0)i[a++]=o%s,o=Math.floor(o/s);return i}function S(e,t){var n=[];while(t-->0)n.push(0);return n.concat(e)}function x(e,t){var n=Math.max(e.length,t.length);if(n<=400)return w(e,t);n=Math.ceil(n/2);var r=e.slice(n),i=e.slice(0,n),s=t.slice(n),o=t.slice(0,n),u=x(i,o),a=x(r,s),f=x(v(i,r),v(o,s));return v(v(u,S(g(g(f,u),a),n)),S(a,2*n))}function T(e,n,r){return e<t?new o(E(n,e),r):new o(w(n,f(e)),r)}function N(e){var n=e.length,r=h(n+n),i=t,s,o,u,a,f;for(u=0;u<n;u++){a=e[u];for(var l=0;l<n;l++)f=e[l],s=a*f+r[u+l],o=Math.floor(s/i),r[u+l]=s-o*i,r[u+l+1]+=o}return c(r),r}function C(e,n){var r=e.length,i=n.length,s=t,o=h(n.length),u=n[i-1],a=Math.ceil(s/(2*u)),f=E(e,a),c=E(n,a),p,d,v,m,g,y,b;f.length<=r&&f.push(0),c.push(0),u=c[i-1];for(d=r-i;d>=0;d--){p=s-1,f[d+i]!==u&&(p=Math.floor((f[d+i]*s+f[d+i-1])/u)),v=0,m=0,y=c.length;for(g=0;g<y;g++)v+=p*c[g],b=Math.floor(v/s),m+=f[d+g]-(v-b*s),v=b,m<0?(f[d+g]=m+s,m=-1):(f[d+g]=m,m=0);while(m!==0){p-=1,v=0;for(g=0;g<y;g++)v+=f[d+g]-s+c[g],v<0?(f[d+g]=v+s,v=0):(f[d+g]=v,v=1);m+=v}o[d]=p}return f=L(f,a)[0],[l(o),l(f)]}function k(e,n){var r=e.length,i=n.length,s=[],o=[],u=t,a,f,c,h,p;while(r){o.unshift(e[--r]);if(O(o,n)<0){s.push(0);continue}f=o.length,c=o[f-1]*u+o[f-2],h=n[i-1]*u+n[i-2],f>i&&(c=(c+1)*u),a=Math.ceil(c/h);do{p=E(n,a);if(O(p,o)<=0)break;a--}while(a);s.push(a),o=g(o,p)}return s.reverse(),[l(s),l(o)]}function L(e,n){var r=e.length,i=h(r),s=t,o,u,a,f;a=0;for(o=r-1;o>=0;--o)f=a*s+e[o],u=p(f/n),a=f-u*n,i[o]=u|0;return[i,a|0]}function A(e,n){var r,i=Q(n),s=e.value,a=i.value,c;if(a===0)throw new Error("Cannot divide by zero");if(e.isSmall)return i.isSmall?[new u(p(s/a)),new u(s%a)]:[G[0],e];if(i.isSmall){if(a===1)return[e,G[0]];if(a==-1)return[e.negate(),G[0]];var h=Math.abs(a);if(h<t){r=L(s,h),c=l(r[0]);var d=r[1];return e.sign&&(d=-d),typeof c=="number"?(e.sign!==i.sign&&(c=-c),[new u(c),new u(d)]):[new o(c,e.sign!==i.sign),new u(d)]}a=f(h)}var v=O(s,a);if(v===-1)return[G[0],e];if(v===0)return[G[e.sign===i.sign?1:-1],G[0]];s.length+a.length<=200?r=C(s,a):r=k(s,a),c=r[0];var m=e.sign!==i.sign,g=r[1],y=e.sign;return typeof c=="number"?(m&&(c=-c),c=new u(c)):c=new o(c,m),typeof g=="number"?(y&&(g=-g),g=new u(g)):g=new o(g,y),[c,g]}function O(e,t){if(e.length!==t.length)return e.length>t.length?1:-1;for(var n=e.length-1;n>=0;n--)if(e[n]!==t[n])return e[n]>t[n]?1:-1;return 0}function M(e){var t=e.abs();if(t.isUnit())return!1;if(t.equals(2)||t.equals(3)||t.equals(5))return!0;if(t.isEven()||t.isDivisibleBy(3)||t.isDivisibleBy(5))return!1;if(t.lesser(25))return!0}function H(e){return(typeof e=="number"||typeof e=="string")&&+Math.abs(e)<=t||e instanceof o&&e.value.length<=1}function B(e,t,n){t=Q(t);var r=e.isNegative(),i=t.isNegative(),s=r?e.not():e,o=i?t.not():t,u=[],a=[],f=!1,l=!1;while(!f||!l)s.isZero()?(f=!0,u.push(r?1:0)):r?u.push(s.isEven()?1:0):u.push(s.isEven()?0:1),o.isZero()?(l=!0,a.push(i?1:0)):i?a.push(o.isEven()?1:0):a.push(o.isEven()?0:1),s=s.over(2),o=o.over(2);var c=[];for(var h=0;h<u.length;h++)c.push(n(u[h],a[h]));var p=bigInt(c.pop()).negate().times(bigInt(2).pow(c.length));while(c.length)p=p.add(bigInt(c.pop()).times(bigInt(2).pow(c.length)));return p}function I(e){var n=e.value,r=typeof n=="number"?n|j:n[0]+n[1]*t|F;return r&-r}function q(e,t){return e=Q(e),t=Q(t),e.greater(t)?e:t}function R(e,t){return e=Q(e),t=Q(t),e.lesser(t)?e:t}function U(e,t){e=Q(e).abs(),t=Q(t).abs();if(e.equals(t))return e;if(e.isZero())return t;if(t.isZero())return e;var n=G[1],r,i;while(e.isEven()&&t.isEven())r=Math.min(I(e),I(t)),e=e.divide(r),t=t.divide(r),n=n.multiply(r);while(e.isEven())e=e.divide(I(e));do{while(t.isEven())t=t.divide(I(t));e.greater(t)&&(i=t,t=e,e=i),t=t.subtract(e)}while(!t.isZero());return n.isUnit()?e:e.multiply(n)}function z(e,t){return e=Q(e).abs(),t=Q(t).abs(),e.divide(U(e,t)).multiply(t)}function W(e,n){e=Q(e),n=Q(n);var r=R(e,n),i=q(e,n),s=i.subtract(r);if(s.isSmall)return r.add(Math.round(Math.random()*s));var a=s.value.length-1,f=[],c=!0;for(var h=a;h>=0;h--){var d=c?s.value[h]:t,v=p(Math.random()*d);f.unshift(v),v<d&&(c=!1)}return f=l(f),r.add(typeof f=="number"?new u(f):new o(f,!1))}function V(e){var t=e.value;return typeof t=="number"&&(t=[t]),t.length===1&&t[0]<=36?"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(t[0]):"<"+t+">"}function $(e,t){t=bigInt(t);if(t.isZero()){if(e.isZero())return"0";throw new Error("Cannot convert nonzero numbers to base 0.")}if(t.equals(-1))return e.isZero()?"0":e.isNegative()?(new Array(1-e)).join("10"):"1"+(new Array(+e)).join("01");var n="";e.isNegative()&&t.isPositive()&&(n="-",e=e.abs());if(t.equals(1))return e.isZero()?"0":n+(new Array(+e+1)).join(1);var r=[],i=e,s;while(i.isNegative()||i.compareAbs(t)>=0){s=i.divmod(t),i=s.quotient;var o=s.remainder;o.isNegative()&&(o=t.minus(o).abs(),i=i.next()),r.push(V(o))}return r.push(V(i)),n+r.reverse().join("")}function J(e){if(a(+e)){var t=+e;if(t===p(t))return new u(t);throw"Invalid integer: "+e}var r=e[0]==="-";r&&(e=e.slice(1));var i=e.split(/e/i);if(i.length>2)throw new Error("Invalid integer: "+f.join("e"));if(i.length===2){var s=i[1];s[0]==="+"&&(s=s.slice(1)),s=+s;if(s!==p(s)||!a(s))throw new Error("Invalid integer: "+s+" is not a valid exponent.");var f=i[0],l=f.indexOf(".");l>=0&&(s-=f.length-l,f=f.slice(0,l)+f.slice(l+1));if(s<0)throw new Error("Cannot include negative exponent part for integers");f+=(new Array(s+1)).join("0"),e=f}var h=/^([0-9][0-9]*)$/.test(e);if(!h)throw new Error("Invalid integer: "+e);var d=[],v=e.length,m=n,g=v-m;while(v>0)d.push(+e.slice(g,v)),g-=m,g<0&&(g=0),v-=m;return c(d),new o(d,r)}function K(e){return a(e)?new u(e):J(e.toString())}function Q(e){return typeof e=="number"?K(e):typeof e=="string"?J(e):e}var t=1e7,n=7,r=9007199254740992,i=f(r),s=Math.log(r);o.prototype.add=function(e){var t,n=Q(e);if(this.sign!==n.sign)return this.subtract(n.negate());var r=this.value,i=n.value;return n.isSmall?new o(m(r,Math.abs(i)),this.sign):new o(v(r,i),this.sign)},o.prototype.plus=o.prototype.add,u.prototype.add=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=this.value;if(n<0!==t.sign)return this.subtract(t.negate());var r=t.value;if(t.isSmall){if(a(n+r))return new u(n+r);r=f(Math.abs(r))}return new o(m(r,Math.abs(n)),n<0)},u.prototype.plus=u.prototype.add,o.prototype.subtract=function(e){var t=Q(e);if(this.sign!==t.sign)return this.add(t.negate());var n=this.value,r=t.value;return t.isSmall?b(n,Math.abs(r),this.sign):y(n,r,this.sign)},o.prototype.minus=o.prototype.subtract,u.prototype.subtract=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=this.value;if(n<0!==t.sign)return this.add(t.negate());var r=t.value;return t.isSmall?new u(n-r):b(r,Math.abs(n),n>=0)},u.prototype.minus=u.prototype.subtract,o.prototype.negate=function(){return new o(this.value,!this.sign)},u.prototype.negate=function(){var e=this.sign,t=new u(-this.value);return t.sign=!e,t},o.prototype.abs=function(){return new o(this.value,!1)},u.prototype.abs=function(){return new u(Math.abs(this.value))},o.prototype.multiply=function(e){var n,r=Q(e),i=this.value,s=r.value,u=this.sign!==r.sign,a;if(r.isSmall){if(s===0)return G[0];if(s===1)return this;if(s===-1)return this.negate();a=Math.abs(s);if(a<t)return new o(E(i,a),u);s=f(a)}return i.length+s.length>4e3?new o(x(i,s),u):new o(w(i,s),u)},o.prototype.times=o.prototype.multiply,u.prototype._multiplyBySmall=function(e){return a(e.value*this.value)?new u(e.value*this.value):T(Math.abs(e.value),f(Math.abs(this.value)),this.sign!==e.sign)},o.prototype._multiplyBySmall=function(e){return e.value===0?G[0]:e.value===1?this:e.value===-1?this.negate():T(Math.abs(e.value),this.value,this.sign!==e.sign)},u.prototype.multiply=function(e){return Q(e)._multiplyBySmall(this)},u.prototype.times=u.prototype.multiply,o.prototype.square=function(){return new o(N(this.value),!1)},u.prototype.square=function(){var e=this.value*this.value;return a(e)?new u(e):new o(N(f(Math.abs(this.value))),!1)},o.prototype.divmod=function(e){var t=A(this,e);return{quotient:t[0],remainder:t[1]}},u.prototype.divmod=o.prototype.divmod,o.prototype.divide=function(e){return A(this,e)[0]},u.prototype.over=u.prototype.divide=o.prototype.over=o.prototype.divide,o.prototype.mod=function(e){return A(this,e)[1]},u.prototype.remainder=u.prototype.mod=o.prototype.remainder=o.prototype.mod,o.prototype.pow=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=this.value,r=t.value,i,s,o;if(r===0)return G[1];if(n===0)return G[0];if(n===1)return G[1];if(n===-1)return t.isEven()?G[1]:G[-1];if(t.sign)return G[0];if(!t.isSmall)throw new Error("The exponent "+t.toString()+" is too large.");if(this.isSmall&&a(i=Math.pow(n,r)))return new u(p(i));s=this,o=G[1];for(;;){r&!0&&(o=o.times(s),--r);if(r===0)break;r/=2,s=s.square()}return o},u.prototype.pow=o.prototype.pow,o.prototype.modPow=function(e,t){e=Q(e),t=Q(t);if(t.isZero())throw new Error("Cannot take modPow with modulus 0");var n=G[1],r=this.mod(t);if(r.isZero())return G[0];while(e.isPositive())e.isOdd()&&(n=n.multiply(r).mod(t)),e=e.divide(2),r=r.square().mod(t);return n},u.prototype.modPow=o.prototype.modPow,o.prototype.compareAbs=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=this.value,r=t.value;return t.isSmall?1:O(n,r)},u.prototype.compareAbs=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=Math.abs(this.value),r=t.value;return t.isSmall?(r=Math.abs(r),n===r?0:n>r?1:-1):-1},o.prototype.compare=function(e){if(e===Infinity)return-1;if(e===-Infinity)return 1;var t=Q(e),n=this.value,r=t.value;return this.sign!==t.sign?t.sign?1:-1:t.isSmall?this.sign?-1:1:O(n,r)*(this.sign?-1:1)},o.prototype.compareTo=o.prototype.compare,u.prototype.compare=function(e){if(e===Infinity)return-1;if(e===-Infinity)return 1;var t=Q(e),n=this.value,r=t.value;return t.isSmall?n==r?0:n>r?1:-1:n<0!==t.sign?n<0?-1:1:n<0?1:-1},u.prototype.compareTo=u.prototype.compare,o.prototype.equals=function(e){return this.compare(e)===0},u.prototype.eq=u.prototype.equals=o.prototype.eq=o.prototype.equals,o.prototype.notEquals=function(e){return this.compare(e)!==0},u.prototype.neq=u.prototype.notEquals=o.prototype.neq=o.prototype.notEquals,o.prototype.greater=function(e){return this.compare(e)>0},u.prototype.gt=u.prototype.greater=o.prototype.gt=o.prototype.greater,o.prototype.lesser=function(e){return this.compare(e)<0},u.prototype.lt=u.prototype.lesser=o.prototype.lt=o.prototype.lesser,o.prototype.greaterOrEquals=function(e){return this.compare(e)>=0},u.prototype.geq=u.prototype.greaterOrEquals=o.prototype.geq=o.prototype.greaterOrEquals,o.prototype.lesserOrEquals=function(e){return this.compare(e)<=0},u.prototype.leq=u.prototype.lesserOrEquals=o.prototype.leq=o.prototype.lesserOrEquals,o.prototype.isEven=function(){return(this.value[0]&1)===0},u.prototype.isEven=function(){return(this.value&1)===0},o.prototype.isOdd=function(){return(this.value[0]&1)===1},u.prototype.isOdd=function(){return(this.value&1)===1},o.prototype.isPositive=function(){return!this.sign},u.prototype.isPositive=function(){return this.value>0},o.prototype.isNegative=function(){return this.sign},u.prototype.isNegative=function(){return this.value<0},o.prototype.isUnit=function(){return!1},u.prototype.isUnit=function(){return Math.abs(this.value)===1},o.prototype.isZero=function(){return!1},u.prototype.isZero=function(){return this.value===0},o.prototype.isDivisibleBy=function(e){var t=Q(e),n=t.value;return n===0?!1:n===1?!0:n===2?this.isEven():this.mod(t).equals(G[0])},u.prototype.isDivisibleBy=o.prototype.isDivisibleBy,o.prototype.isPrime=function(){var t=M(this);if(t!==e)return t;var n=this.abs(),r=n.prev(),i=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19],s=r,o,u,a,f;while(s.isEven())s=s.divide(2);for(a=0;a<i.length;a++){f=bigInt(i[a]).modPow(s,n);if(f.equals(G[1])||f.equals(r))continue;for(u=!0,o=s;u&&o.lesser(r);o=o.multiply(2))f=f.square().mod(n),f.equals(r)&&(u=!1);if(u)return!1}return!0},u.prototype.isPrime=o.prototype.isPrime,o.prototype.isProbablePrime=function(t){var n=M(this);if(n!==e)return n;var r=this.abs(),i=t===e?5:t;for(var s=0;s<i;s++){var o=bigInt.randBetween(2,r.minus(2));if(!o.modPow(r.prev(),r).isUnit())return!1}return!0},u.prototype.isProbablePrime=o.prototype.isProbablePrime,o.prototype.next=function(){var e=this.value;return this.sign?b(e,1,this.sign):new o(m(e,1),this.sign)},u.prototype.next=function(){var e=this.value;return e+1<r?new u(e+1):new o(i,!1)},o.prototype.prev=function(){var e=this.value;return this.sign?new o(m(e,1),!0):b(e,1,this.sign)},u.prototype.prev=function(){var e=this.value;return e-1>-r?new u(e-1):new o(i,!0)};var _=[1];while(_[_.length-1]<=t)_.push(2*_[_.length-1]);var D=_.length,P=_[D-1];o.prototype.shiftLeft=function(e){if(!H(e))return e.isNegative()?this.shiftRight(e.abs()):this.times(G[2].pow(e));e=+e;if(e<0)return this.shiftRight(-e);var t=this;while(e>=D)t=t.multiply(P),e-=D-1;return t.multiply(_[e])},u.prototype.shiftLeft=o.prototype.shiftLeft,o.prototype.shiftRight=function(e){var t;if(!H(e))return e.isNegative()?this.shiftLeft(e.abs()):(t=this.divmod(G[2].pow(e)),t.remainder.isNegative()?t.quotient.prev():t.quotient);e=+e;if(e<0)return this.shiftLeft(-e);var n=this;while(e>=D){if(n.isZero())return n;t=A(n,P),n=t[1].isNegative()?t[0].prev():t[0],e-=D-1}return t=A(n,_[e]),t[1].isNegative()?t[0].prev():t[0]},u.prototype.shiftRight=o.prototype.shiftRight,o.prototype.not=function(){return this.negate().prev()},u.prototype.not=o.prototype.not,o.prototype.and=function(e){return B(this,e,function(e,t){return e&t})},u.prototype.and=o.prototype.and,o.prototype.or=function(e){return B(this,e,function(e,t){return e|t})},u.prototype.or=o.prototype.or,o.prototype.xor=function(e){return B(this,e,function(e,t){return e^t})},u.prototype.xor=o.prototype.xor;var j=1<<30,F=(t&-t)*(t&-t)|j,X=function(e,t){var n=G[0],r=G[1],i=e.length;if(2<=t&&t<=36&&i<=s/Math.log(t))return new u(parseInt(e,t));t=Q(t);var o=[],a,f=e[0]==="-";for(a=f?1:0;a<e.length;a++){var l=e[a].toLowerCase(),c=l.charCodeAt(0);if(48<=c&&c<=57)o.push(Q(l));else if(97<=c&&c<=122)o.push(Q(l.charCodeAt(0)-87));else{if(l!=="<")throw new Error(l+" is not a valid character");var h=a;do a++;while(e[a]!==">");o.push(Q(e.slice(h+1,a)))}}o.reverse();for(a=0;a<o.length;a++)n=n.add(o[a].times(r)),r=r.times(t);return f?n.negate():n};o.prototype.toString=function(t){t===e&&(t=10);if(t!==10)return $(this,t);var n=this.value,r=n.length,i=String(n[--r]),s="0000000",o;while(--r>=0)o=String(n[r]),i+=s.slice(o.length)+o;var u=this.sign?"-":"";return u+i},u.prototype.toString=function(t){return t===e&&(t=10),t!=10?$(this,t):String(this.value)},o.prototype.valueOf=function(){return+this.toString()},o.prototype.toJSNumber=o.prototype.valueOf,u.prototype.valueOf=function(){return this.value},u.prototype.toJSNumber=u.prototype.valueOf;var G=function(e,t){return typeof e=="undefined"?G[0]:typeof t!="undefined"?+t===10?Q(e):X(e,t):Q(e)};for(var Y=0;Y<1e3;Y++)G[Y]=new u(Y),Y>0&&(G[-Y]=new u(-Y));return G.one=G[1],G.zero=G[0],G.minusOne=G[-1],G.max=q,G.min=R,G.gcd=U,G.lcm=z,G.isInstance=function(e){return e instanceof o||e instanceof u},G.randBetween=W,G}();typeof module!="undefined"&&module.hasOwnProperty("exports")&&(module.exports=bigInt);


function compute(){
  var base = bigInt(document.getElementById('base').value);
  var exponent = bigInt(document.getElementById('exponent').value);
  var modulo = bigInt(document.getElementById('modulo').value);

  var res = base.modPow(exponent, modulo);
  document.getElementById('result').value = res;
}
```

```html
<label>Base:<input id="base" value="3"></label><br>
<label>Exponent:<input id="exponent" value="23984081230374123749712934791249172394719237497219347129374498"></label><br>
<label>Modulo:<input id="modulo" value="112457129983317064494133258034491756790943511028023366901014968560410379195027"></label><br>
<input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="compute()"><br>
Result: <input id="result">
```

The result [seems to be exact](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E23984081230374123749712934791249172394719237497219347129374498+mod+112457129983317064494133258034491756790943511028023366901014968560410379195027).

PS: The [`modPow` implementation](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/7d926cb04d3e50ecc7832c4b96cc860adadd2836/BigInteger.js#L595-L608) is actually quite readable.

Comment: Looks good. BTW the Diffie-Hellman literature uses `G` for your `base` and `P` for your `modulo` (sometimes lower case `g` and  `p`). I think they stand for "generator" and "prime".

Comment: Thanks! This solved ALL of my problems, now I just need to figure out how to use these shared numbers

Comment: There is currently a [bug](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/pull/65) when the base and the exponent are equals to 0

Answer (score 1):

I found a really efficient way to solve this problem! It requires calculating the values before hand, my code goes as follows:

```
function KeyGen(p1, p2, n) {
    var inc = 0;
    var bin = [];
    bin[0] = p1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n.toString(2).length; i++){
      bin[i] = (bin[i-1] * bin[i-1]) % p2;
      console.log(bin[i] + " and " + bin[i-1]);
    }
    console.log("loop");
    return n.toString(2).split('').reverse().reduce(function(total, char) {
        if(char === '1') {
              total = (total * bin[inc]) % p2;
              console.log("current "+ total);
            }
        inc++;
        return total % p2;
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: I am quite positive it will still be quicker to use bit math.  Strings and arrays are big slow objects with methods to call, properties to look up, and unpredictable return types.  Strings are further immutable and are getting copied all over.  Integers are tiny piles of bits that can be instantly transformed into the bits you want with no allocating, no call, no lookup, no uncertainty of type.

Comment: I understand it would be faster, but this by far suits my needs, it can do 256 bit operations in seconds!

Comment: Have you tested it with an actual 256 bit number?  That's way past the precision limit.

Comment: I think neither approach is going to work then.  Best bet will be a typed array of integers.  Will likely do 256 bits in milliseconds.

Comment: This executed in seconds, this is an actual 256 bit number generated for diffe-hellman `KeyGen(3, 112457129983317064494133258034491756790943511028023366901014968560410379195027, 23984081230374123749712934791249172394719237497219347129374498);`

Comment: Appins, this is not *overtly* the same algorithm as before.

Comment: It executes the same equation and works by a similar mechanic.

Comment: What JS engine / browser are you in?  It must be using bignums, I get gibberish in FF all the time with far less demanded precision.

Comment: I'm having trouble too, nothing is working

Comment: AppIns, in reponse to this, I have added something to my own answer.